# How to retrieve lost mongo data from cpanel

Tags: linux, database, mongodb, cpanel

I updated the cpanel linux server's of over the weekend, I had mongo install with a ton of databases and collections. The update Its seemed to have removed all the data from the mongo db.

I have checked the storage size, I did not see any drastic change, which gives me reason to believe that the data is still there but maybe pointing to the wrong folder.

The default path is set to var/lib/mongo in the [mongod.config](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/) file. I've run the command
`mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`. Its working.

The mongo application is working, everything else seems fine. It does not seem to be any missing files, only the database and collections I had before the server os update.

If anyone know what I can do to troubleshoot or retrieve my data somehow, that would be greatly appreciated.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

*I have tried looking over folders where mongo db data is saved. Online they say /data/db is another default path, but do not have that folder on my server.

I have tried using `mongorestore`, that did not work.*

Comment: You linked to docs from Mongo version **2.4**. Is that the version you were on before the upgrade? There would many binary changes to the DB between 2.4 and 7.x (you haven't mentioned what you upgraded to). Read the ["Upgrade MongoDB to X.Y" section](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/2.6-upgrade/) for each version between 2.4 and your current one to see the correct way to upgrade. Not all are _binary-compatible "drop-in" upgrades_. Check your mongo logs for error messages triggered by having incompatible data and server versions.

Comment: You will likely need to do 2.4 → 3 → 4 → 5 → 6 → 7. Or use [Extended JSON v1](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json-v1/) to upgrade from 2.x to current. Also, `mongodump` and `mongorestore` have their own [version compatibilities](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/#mongodb-server-compatibility), so you'll need to match the version of the DB tool with the mongo version.